# Django ConnectionError (urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection) while posting from Django admin

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

Error info:

```
Exception Type: ConnectionError at /admin/items/country/add/
Exception Value: ConnectionError (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x111377110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
61] Connection refused) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x111377110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] 
Connection refused)
```

I am getting this connection error while saving the post from Django admin. I have a MYSQL database with settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mystic_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
```

I am a newbie to Django Python. kindly request a solution to this issue ?

Traceback:

> File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
>     616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
>     233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
>     1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
>     34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
>     30.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
>     145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
>     1467.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
>     1078.         obj.save()
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
>     710.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
>     747.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
>     201.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/signals.py" in handle_save
>     52.                 index.update_object(instance, using=using)
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py" in update_object
>     284.                 backend.update(self, [instance])
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py" in update
>     190.         bulk(self.conn, prepped_docs, index=self.index_name, doc_type='modelresult')
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/**init**.py" in bulk
>     188.     for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/**init**.py" in streaming_bulk
>     160.         for result in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions, raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, **kwargs):
>   File "/Users/MacbookAir/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/**init**.py" in _process_bulk_chunk
>     89.             raise e

```
Exception Type: ConnectionError at /admin/items/country/add/
Exception Value: ConnectionError (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x111377110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
61] Connection refused) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x111377110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] 
Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 2):

i assume your database is hosted locally

so try changing this in your settings file for the database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mystic_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', or localhost whatever you prefer
        'PORT': '',
}
}
```

Comment: did you put localhost inside single quotes?? try putting 3306 in the port inside singlequotes and you sure the user name and password you are setting is correct? and do you have a password for mysql? if not keep it blank

Comment: Yes inside single quote .I set port to 3306 and problem still persists. User name and password is correct. Yes I have a password for sql and is set correct.

Comment: did you installed mysqlclient?? if not use pip install mysqlclient first then check

Comment: Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.10.  Still it shows error !

Comment: do one thing post the stacktrace

Comment: this is not the full traceback, upload the last part that is importany

Comment: Updated the last part

Comment: is there anything like url or which you are adding or anything which is getting connected to internet to download anything from the add part??

Comment: I am using  google api for geo location in the application . But that not related to this admin post.

Comment: but from the error after even correcting the database details, its supposed to be connected with getting some data from the internet as urllib3 is the socket which connects to internet to get data, may be you should allow it in the firewall or try running the project using sudo

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem because of improper installing of elastic search which I was using along with haystack module. Elastic search is built using Java, and requires at least Java 8 in order to run. Once I installed the same, the connection error urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection got alright.

Comment: I am facing the same error, what do you mean by saying you installed the same? do you refer to install java 8?